# Specman: What is the difference between "define" and "#define"?

Tags: specman, e

What is the difference between `define` with and without hash mark?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you refer to the simple C-like preprocessor statements of the form `#define`*`name`**`value`* (and not to `define as` or `define as computed` macros), there is no difference at all. The `#` in this syntax was supposed to be mandatory, but for historical and backward compatibility reasons it was left optional.